# How to save many similar information from list? (coding question)

Tags: java, file, project

I have a file with format (ID/Name/Doctor’s Name/Date/Time) with 2 tabs between each column.

That file represents current appointment.

What I want to do is that when it comes to changing appointment, if patient has 1 appointment, there’s no problem there.

However, if the patient had more than 1 appointment, how can I display all appointments so that patient can choose which appointment to change? There must be a way where I can save all appointments associated with patient.

Comment: Are you looking for design guidance or is there a coding question associated?  It isn't clear from the question how to phrase an answer.  Maybe elaborate with more of your thinking of where the puzzle may be and how we may assist in answering.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow community :)

Judging from the question, you want to store a list of data against a single patient.For this purpose, I would suggest you use a `HashMap` with `key` as the patient's unique `ID` and `value` as `List` of person's information read from the file.

The hashmap declaration should look like this.

`Map<String,List<Person>> patientRecord = new HashMap<>();` It would be better to create a new `Person` class for this and load each data of the patient to this and the store it as a list in the hashmap

Comment: What do you mean value as list?

Comment: You can find the answer here :  https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/arraylist-in-java/